# How can I use the Python library networkx from Mathematica?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, interoperability, external-calls, python

Is there an easy way to access the Python library [networkx](https://networkx.github.io) from Mathematica?

The improvements to [`ExternalEvaluate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ExternalEvaluate.html) in Mathematica 12.0 should make this feasible.

Comment: Perhaps also worth noting the existence of a NetworkXObject repository function https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/NetworkXObject/

Answer (score 35):

Mathematica 12.0 brings two new features that make this easier to do than it was before:

- [`ExternalFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ExternalFunction.html)
- [Wolfram Client for Python](https://github.com/WolframResearch/WolframClientForPython)

Below we implement a function `nxFunction` that automatically handles translating Mathematica expressions of interest to Python, as well as converting the results back.  The usage will be

```
nxFunction["someNetworkxFunction"][graph, positionalArg2, "keyword1" -> keywordArgValue]
```

Here is a barebones example that serves as a proof of concept.  (Improvements posted as additional answers are very welcome!)

#### Set up external session

First, make sure that the Python you are using has networkx installed, and start an external session.  In the below example I am using an Anaconda virtualenv named "py37" on macOS. Adjust as necessary for your machine.

```
py = StartExternalSession[{"Python", 
   "Executable" -> AbsoluteFileName["~/anaconda/envs/py37/bin/python"]}]
```

Load the package:

```
ExternalEvaluate[py, "import networkx as nx"]
```

#### Mathematica -> Python conversion

We are going to use two Python helper function to translate arguments into the correct form. Most networkx functions that take a graph will take it as the first argument. This Python function takes a vertex list, an edge list and a graph type, and translates them to a networkx object. The rest of the arguments/options are passed as normal arguments / keyword arguments.

```
nxFun = ExternalFunction[py, "
  def nxfun(vertices, edges, gtype, fname, args, kwargs):
    fun = getattr(nx, fname)
    GraphClass = {'su': nx.Graph, 'sd': nx.DiGraph, 'mu': nx.MultiGraph, 'md': nx.MultiDiGraph}[gtype]
    g = GraphClass()
    g.add_nodes_from(vertices)
    g.add_edges_from(edges)
    return fun(g, *args, **kwargs)
  "]
```

The following is for calling networkx functions that do not take a graph argument:

```
nxPlainFun = ExternalFunction[py, "
  def nxplainfun(fname, args, kwargs):
    fun = getattr(nx, fname)
    return fun(*args, **kwargs)
  "]
```

Now we create Mathematica functions that call the above Python functions:

```
ClearAll[nxGraphQ]
nxGraphQ[_?MixedGraphQ] = False;
nxGraphQ[_?GraphQ] = True;
nxGraphQ[_] = False;

(* first argument is a graph *)
nxFunction[name_][g_?nxGraphQ, args___, kwargs : OptionsPattern[]] :=    
  nxFun[
  VertexList[g],
  List @@@ EdgeList[g],
  If[MultigraphQ[g],
   If[DirectedGraphQ[g], "md", "mu"],
   If[DirectedGraphQ[g], "sd", "su"]
   ],
  name,
  {args},
  Association[kwargs]
 ]

(* first argument is not a graph *)
nxFunction[name_][args___, kwargs : OptionsPattern[]] :=
 nxPlainFun[
  name, {args}, Association[kwargs]
 ]
```

#### Python -> Mathematica conversion

We create a custom serializer for networkx graphs, as described here:

- https://reference.wolfram.com/language/WolframClientForPython/docpages/advanced_usages.html#extending-serialization-writing-an-encoder

```
ExternalEvaluate[py,
 "
 from wolframclient.language import wl
 from wolframclient.serializers import wolfram_encoder

 @wolfram_encoder.dispatch(nx.Graph)
 def encode_animal(serializer, graph):
     return serializer.encode(wl.Graph(graph.nodes, wl.Apply(wl.UndirectedEdge, graph.edges, [1])))

 @wolfram_encoder.dispatch(nx.DiGraph)
 def encode_animal(serializer, graph):
     return serializer.encode(wl.Graph(graph.nodes, wl.Apply(wl.DirectedEdge, graph.edges, [1])))
 "]
```

#### Try it out

Create a test graph:

```
SeedRandom[42]
g = RandomGraph[{10, 20}, DirectedEdges -> True]
```

Compute the betweenness:

```
nxFunction["betweenness_centrality"][g]
(* <|1 -> 0.256944, 2 -> 0.0416667, 3 -> 0., 4 -> 0.333333, 
 5 -> 0.0277778, 6 -> 0.236111, 7 -> 0.25, 8 -> 0.111111, 9 -> 0., 
 10 -> 0.0763889|> *)
```

Compute betweenness without normalization (and test keyword arguments):

```
nxFunction["betweenness_centrality"][g, "normalized" -> False]
(* <|1 -> 18.5, 2 -> 3., 3 -> 0., 4 -> 24., 5 -> 2., 6 -> 17., 
 7 -> 18., 8 -> 8., 9 -> 0., 10 -> 5.5|> *)
```

Compare with Mathematica's result:

```
BetweennessCentrality[g]
(* {18.5, 3., 0., 24., 2., 17., 18., 8., 0., 5.5} *)
```

A networkx function that returns a graph:

```
nxFunction["grid_graph"][{3, 4}]
```

[image]

```
Graph[nxFunction["margulis_gabber_galil_graph"][6], 
 VertexLabels -> Automatic]
```

[image]

```
nxFunction["hexagonal_lattice_graph"][6, 7]
```

[image]

Modify existing graphs:

```
nxFunction["ego_graph"][GridGraph[{5, 6}], 1, 3]
```

[image]

```
nxFunction["mycielskian"][GridGraph[{3, 3}]]
```

[image]

Compute minimal cycle basis:

```
nxFunction["minimum_cycle_basis"][GridGraph[{3, 4}]]

(* {{1, 2, 4, 5}, {2, 3, 5, 6}, {4, 5, 7, 8}, {5, 6, 8, 9}, {7, 8, 10, 11}, {8, 9, 11, 12}} *)
```

This is a first proof of concept. Improvement and suggestions are most welcome. I encourage everyone to post new answers either improving this one, or presenting independent approaches.

Comment: +1 as always!!!! For clarification: what limitations, if any, have you found with the python=>mma conversion?